# Mocking does not work in parameterized test Spock

Tags: unit-testing, groovy, spock

So I am trying to learn Spock and I am struggling with creation of tests.

```
private WeaponWriter writer;
@Shared
def emptyObject = Mock(Weapon)
@Shared
def weaponMocked = Mock(Weapon)

def: "should flatten object"(){
    given: 
        emptyObject.content() >> ""
        weaponMocked.content() >> "BF Sword"
        List<Weapon> weaponList = Arrays.asList(weapon1, weapon2)
        writer = new WeaponWriter(weaponList)
    when:
        def text = writer.writeWeapon()
    then:
        text == expectedText
    where:
        weapon1     | weapon2       | expectedText
        emptyObject | emptyObject   | "Headline"
        weaponMocked| emptyObject   | "Headline" + "BF Sword"
        weaponMocked| weaponMocked  | "Headline" + "BF Sword" + "BF Sword"      
}
```

As you can see, I want to test class with method which convert list of `Weapon` to one string.
And I have three test cases, and only first one is working correctly.

`WeaponWriter#writeWeapon` is just iterating over the list of weapons and for each of them calling `Weapon#content` and then combines them into one String.

From what I see for some reason mocking of `weaponMocked.content() >> "BF Sword"` does not return BF Sword, anyone know why?

---

When I am not using paramtrized test everything works ok.

Comment: Please edit your question, turning it into an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). I cannot see your classes under test `Weapon` and `WeaponWriter`, so I cannot say anything intelligent about why your test fails. If you want answers, not pure speculation, please improve the question. Thank you. BTW, `@Shared` is generally overused and potentially dangerous because tests ideally should not have side effects on each other. Why do you think you need it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, I think I have spotted it: As I said, you use `@Shared` mocks instead of creating new ones for each iteration of each feature method, probably because you want to use them from within the `where:` block. Then you are trying to stub methods for those mocks from within your test even though shared variables should be initialised either directly during declaration or from a `setupSpec()` method. What is even worse, you are trying to re-initialise the stub methods for each iteration, which definitely is a bad idea.

Let us assume we have these classes under test (I am using Groovy, can also be similar Java classes):

```
package de.scrum_master.stackoverflow.q64013999

class Weapon {
  private String name

  Weapon(String name) {
    this.name = name
  }

  String content() {
    name
  }
}
```

```
package de.scrum_master.stackoverflow.q64013999

class WeaponWriter {
  private List<Weapon> weaponList

  WeaponWriter(List<Weapon> weaponList) {
    this.weaponList = weaponList
  }

  String writeWeapon() {
    "Headline" + weaponList*.content().join("")
  }
}
```

So now you have at least two choices:

**1. Initialise the stubs directly during mock creation:**

```
package de.scrum_master.stackoverflow.q64013999

import spock.lang.Shared
import spock.lang.Specification
import spock.lang.Unroll

class WeaponWriterTest extends Specification {
  private WeaponWriter writer
  @Shared
  def emptyObject = Mock(Weapon) {
    content() >> ""
  }
  @Shared
  def weaponMocked = Mock(Weapon) {
    content() >> "BF Sword"
  }

  @Unroll
  def "flatten weapon list into '#expectedText'"() {
    given:
    writer = new WeaponWriter([weapon1, weapon2])

    expect:
    writer.writeWeapon() == expectedText

    where:
    weapon1      | weapon2      | expectedText
    emptyObject  | emptyObject  | "Headline"
    weaponMocked | emptyObject  | "Headline" + "BF Sword"
    weaponMocked | weaponMocked | "Headline" + "BF Sword" + "BF Sword"
  }
}
```

**2. Initialise the stubs in `setupSpec()`:**

```
package de.scrum_master.stackoverflow.q64013999

import spock.lang.Shared
import spock.lang.Specification
import spock.lang.Unroll

class WeaponWriterTest extends Specification {
  private WeaponWriter writer
  @Shared
  def emptyObject = Mock(Weapon)
  @Shared
  def weaponMocked = Mock(Weapon)

  def setupSpec() {
    emptyObject.content() >> ""
    weaponMocked.content() >> "BF Sword"
  }

  @Unroll
  def "flatten weapon list into '#expectedText'"() {
    given:
    writer = new WeaponWriter([weapon1, weapon2])

    expect:
    writer.writeWeapon() == expectedText

    where:
    weapon1      | weapon2      | expectedText
    emptyObject  | emptyObject  | "Headline"
    weaponMocked | emptyObject  | "Headline" + "BF Sword"
    weaponMocked | weaponMocked | "Headline" + "BF Sword" + "BF Sword"
  }
}
```

Please, please provide an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) by yourself next time. Thank you. This was your free shot for me doing your job, asking a proper question.